# Google colab: downloading dataframes as csv or excel or google sheets

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, export-to-csv

I am trying to save a dataframe from my google colab code to a csv, excel, or google sheet so that i can work with it in that form. I have been successful in downloading it however the format in the excel doc is off.

I want three columns (year/mean/std) which i have in my dataframe. when I download it, it labels the columns but the data doesnt fall into place and instead all stays in the first column.
[image from google colab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/am9hD.png)
[image of csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xItMa.png)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using **tab** separation. You should remove `sep='\t'` and download again.